# Using Homebrew to install GCC-built boost libraries on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, boost, homebrew

Is it possible to use Homebrew to install boost libraries compiled with GCC (instead of Clang)?

I have tried pointing HOMEBREW_CXX to my Homebrew version of GCC, but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

If not, I can always modify the configure file following the suggestion in this answer:

[How to install Boost with specified compiler (say GCC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25346443/how-to-install-boost-with-specified-compiler-say-gcc)

Comment: And is it possible to install both simultaneously? Sadly, it seems the installed libraries don't have the suffix to help CMake to distinguish which one use for each compiler.

Answer (score 6):

`brew install boost --cc=gcc-4.9` will do it. `install --cc` is described in `man brew`.